# Search result with multiple tables relation in Laravel6

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make search function with relation.
I could display all result using relation And an another code, simple one table search and get result works fine.
but I can't combine those two.
Could you teach me how to combine multiple tables into search function please?

```
 public function order(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    $products = Product::All();
    $products = Product::with('categori')
        ->join('creators', 'creators.id', '=', 'products.creator_id')
        ->join('categoris', 'categoris.id', '=', 'products.categori_id')
        ->join('branches', 'branches.id', '=', 'products.br_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'products.user_id')
        ->join('colors', 'colors.id', '=', 'products.color_id')
        ->get();

    $products = Product::when($data['categori_id'], function ($query, $categori_id) {
        return $query->where('categori_id', $categori_id);
    })->
    when($data['color_id'], function ($query, $color_id) {
        return $query->where('color_id', $color_id);
    })->get();

 
    //return view('result_fb', compact('images'));
    $data = array(
        'title' => 'index',
        'no'    => 1,
        'products'  => $products,
    );
    return view('product.result', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you need 'categori' relation to be loaded or not as there are few $products without it. For general, you can combine all your $products queries to one as follows:

```
$products = Product::join('creators', 'creators.id', '=', 'products.creator_id')
        ->join('categoris', 'categoris.id', '=', 'products.categori_id')
        ->join('branches', 'branches.id', '=', 'products.br_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'products.user_id')
        ->join('colors', 'colors.id', '=', 'products.color_id')
        ->when($data['categori_id'], function ($query, $categori_id) use ($data) {
            return $query->where('categori_id', $data['categori_id']);
        })
        ->when($data['color_id'], function ($query) use ($data) {
            return $query->where('color_id', $data['color_id']);
        })->get();
```

If you want to use eager loading with eloquent rather then join, you can use like

```
$products = Product::with(['creator','categori','branch','user','color'])
        ->when($data['categori_id'], function ($query, $categori_id) use ($data) {
            return $query->where('categori_id', $data['categori_id']);
        })
        ->when($data['color_id'], function ($query) use ($data) {
            return $query->where('color_id', $data['color_id']);
        })->get();
```

But for that you Product model should have relations with same name as follows for categori relation:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function categori()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Categori::class,'categori_id','id);
    }
}
```

Same way you have to define for all relation used for product.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I'm relation beginner. Could you give me some time. I will report you later.

Comment: Sure, happy coding :)

Comment: Sorry for late. Thank you very much. It worked very well. And your explanation was very kind. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$products = Product::with('categori')
    ->join('creators', 'creators.id', '=', 'products.creator_id')
    ->join('categoris', 'categoris.id', '=', 'products.categori_id')
    ->join('branches', 'branches.id', '=', 'products.br_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'products.user_id')
    ->join('colors', 'colors.id', '=', 'products.color_id')
    ->when($data['categori_id'], function ($query, $categori_id) {
      return $query->where('categori_id', $categori_id);
    })
    ->when($data['color_id'], function ($query, $color_id) {
    return $query->where('color_id', $color_id);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm relation begginer so Could you wait little more please? I will report you later.